laravel signed route - route not defined
I am trying to define a signed route in Laravel 9 and test it.
I have this route defined in web.php:
Route::get('/unsubscribe/{email}', [NewsletterController::class, 'unsubscribe'])->name('unsubscribe')->middleware('signed');

The unsubscribe method is defined as follows:
public function unsubscribe($email, Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401);
    }
     dd($email);
}

and in my HomeController - to test it (to view the page using the URL):
// todo - test
$url = URL::signedRoute('unsubscribe', ['email' => 'test_rapid@test.com']);
dd($url);

I get the following error:
Route [unsubscribe] not defined.

Why? Am I missing something?
UPDATE
It seems the problem was with the cache...
I allready tried route:clear, cache:clear, but no luck. After restarting the server it`s working.

Please run php artisan route:list to see if the route is registered. Depending on your setup it is possible that the route is cached.
You can run php artisan route:clear

Here are other useful commands to help you test and get familiar with php artisan tinker. It allows you to run commands directly from terminal so you don't actually have to update your HomeController.
Example execution via tinker:
php artisan tinker     
Psy Shell v0.12.4 (PHP 8.3.8 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> URL::signedRoute('unsubscribe', ['email' => 'test_rapid@test.com']);
= "http://localhost/unsubscribe/test_rapid@test.com?signature=3dc33cb4de04a35bdce0056e5e4533d6a477b16c4f6ed941514f83b907c122b5"


@ErsinDemirtas it shows in the list of routes, I tested already with route:clear, cache:clear but no luck. After testing with tinker, it seems to work now...that's very strange :/

php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:list
Clear the route cache and check if your route is listed.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
